# Convert stored string that contain html tag into html text formatting

Tags: html, string, angular, typescript, text-formatting

I have an Angular project that stores data inside firebase. The data is stored as string (`prdName: string;`) inside the database. I want to ask if is it possible if i put a html tag inside the string like `<b>this is text</b>` and store it and then bind/view them as html text format? (the text become bold)

[image: firebase]

```js
//service.ts
getData() {
  this.List = this.firebase.list('Product');
  return this.List;
}

insertProduct(Product: Product) {
  this.productList.push({
    prdName: Product.prdName,
    prdCategory: Product.prdCategory,
    prdSup: Product.prdSup,
    prdImage: Product.prdImage,
    prdDescription: Product.prdDescription
  });
}
```

```js
//component.ts
ngOnInit() {
  var x = this.ListService.getData();
  x.snapshotChanges().subscribe(item => {
    this.List = [];
    item.forEach(element => {
      var y = element.payload.toJSON();
      y["$prdKey"] = element.key;
      this.List.push(y as List);
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<!--component.html-->
<label>Product Name: </label> {{ListService.selectedProduct.prdName}}
```

Please let me know if more snippets are needed. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use innerHtml to bind html tags :

```
<div [innerHTML]="ListService.selectedProduct.prdName"></div>
```

Check this : https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#!#property-binding-or-interpolation-

Answer (score 1):

I used such pipe in my project to make it work right

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Pipe({ name: 'safeHtml'})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform  {
  constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(value) {
    return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
}
```

then in the place where you want to have your html you simply do

```
<div [innerHTML]="someHtmlContent | safeHtml"></div>
```

pipe is needed to make this html content trusted, more information about this:

https://angular.io/guide/security#bypass-security-apis